# Using Numpy to update one column by the square root of those column values

Tags: python, numpy

Given an array update the second column by the square root of those values.

Comment: Did you try assigning the result of `np.sqrt` to that column?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As rafaelc suggested, you can use np.sqrt on a specific column.

```
a = np.array([[1.,2.,3.],[1.,2.,3.]])
a[:,1] = np.sqrt(a[:,1])
```

`a` has two rows and three columns. `a[:,1]` is the second column.

Comment: I was trying something like :    a= np.array([[1.,2.,3.],[1.,2.,3.]])                       a1=np.sqrt(a[::,0])
a=(a1, a), Which I know is wrong